# Python dont showing version

Tags: windows, python

I have just recovered Windows 10 (Because my python didn't work correctly).
Before i installed python, i checked version of my python (probably it should return error message?):

```
PS C:\Users\chote> Python -v
Python
PS C:\Users\chote>
```

Then I just installed latest version of python from official site, and in new terminal process i got same picture.

Something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Just incorrect option :-)

```
python --version
python -V
python -VV
```

Comment: you need `python --version`, not `python -version`

Comment: @phuclv Indeed you do! Thanks, fixed :-)